# Numpy, getting data from column A or B depending if condition is met to create column C

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 columns of data in my array that are essentially 1 column of useful information. However they come from different sources which is why they are in 2 columns.

What I'd like to do is take the value from the first or second column, depending on if a condition is met. This value would then be inserted into a new column. Thus my new column would be essentially only the useful information from column 1 and 2. If the condition is not met in either column then it just enters a blank.

Is there an easy and efficient way to do this in numpy?

Here is a sample table:

```
Name       Gathered_Name
John       0
0          Jack
0          0
```

And my result would be something like:

```
Column3
John
Jack
"" <--empty string
```

Don't worry about the condition, I have worked out the regex to handle that...Assume in this scenario, the condition is `if != 0`

Comment: Aside: most of the time when people have string values and/or named columns, they'd be better off using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org).

Comment: This sounds like `np.where`.  e.g., `np.where(Name != 0, Name, Gathered_Name)`